# How do I replace a harddrive that is in a two-way mirror storage space on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, storage-spaces

I have a storage space in Windows 8 doing a two-way mirror on three harddrives. The sizes are 297GB, 189GB, and 70GB. I would like to replace the 70GB HD with a larger one. My thought was to remove that drive from the space via the Storage Space control panel, shutdown, replace HD with bigger drive, reboot, add new HD to the storage space.

I can't find any options to remove a HD from a storage space in the control panel. Should I just shutdown and swap out the small drive or is there another process for safely replacing the old HD? (By the way, the old HD is still operational.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I found on the [Building Windows 8 blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/):

> **Q) How do I replace a working drive with a bigger one (or just cycle
> drives)? Does it require a “rebuild”?**
>
> As long as you have created mirrored or parity spaces, you can always
> simply remove a physical disk within the pool, and add a different
> (perhaps larger) one. Within a short period of time, the impacted
> spaces will automatically be resynchronized (the Storage Spaces design
> optimizes this operation to be faster than traditional RAID rebuilds).
> You can determine whether all spaces are healthy – i.e. data has been
> resynchronized so as to maintain the designated number of copies
> –either via Control Panel or via PowerShell commands.

[Virtualizing storage for scale, resiliency, and efficiency](https://web.archive.org/web/20151205145736/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/01/05/virtualizing-storage-for-scale-resiliency-and-efficiency.aspx)

So, my understanding is to just pull the drive, replace, and let it do its thing.

Comment: This still leaves an unknown area for how to deal with simple storage spaces with no resiliency.

Answer (score 0):

If your mirror is setup with the 297GB drive mirrored to the 189GB+70GB, you could break the mirror, replace the 70GB drive and recreate the mirror. I would suggest replacing the 70GB drive with something larger than 297GB so that you are not mirroring onto JBOD.

Please confirm the configuration of the mirror before removing any drive. You can find this out by the capacity of the logical volume; it should be less than 189+70 (259GB). If that is correct, you should have no problems performing the swap. If instead, your logical volume is 189+70+297 (556GB), you actually have a JBOD array, not a mirror. This means no redundancy, and removing any drive from the array would provide complete data loss. For this scenario, use a disk cloning utility (ghost/dd) to clone the data to the larger replacement drive and then create a RAID1 mirror from that drive to your other drives.