# Remove drive from Windows Storage Spaces

Tags: windows-8, storage-spaces

I have build a HTPC with the drives in the same case. 
It runs on W8 and uses Storage Spaces to manage the data and create a single cluster for all the hard drives which is easier to manage in XBMC.

But now: 
My motherboard only has 4 sata ports and I need more space so I'll have to replace a hard drive for a new one.

How do I remove the data from a single hard drive in the storage space?
I have a 1.5tb drive and would like to change it for a 3tb drive. I currently have enough space in the cluster to move the data to the other drives but I can't find a way to move it. 
I have no resilience or mirroring installed on the cluster so I can't just yank the drive out and depend on rebuilding the drive.

EDIT: I know that it would be easy IF I had the parity, but I don't and that's why the question is being asked.

Comment: If only you had mirrored or parity spaces, you could have simply [replaced the drive](http://superuser.com/a/485280/138343).

Answer (score 2):

Transfer your data to an external drive, swap your internal drives, build a new storage space (with parity if you expect to upgrade again), and transfer your data back. There is no way to "move" storage space data between physical drives within the array.